# How to get AWS_Completer for AWS CLI on Windows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autocomplete, git-bash, aws-cli

I want to have `aws_completer` on Windows 10 in GitBash terminal.

[AWS docs say](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-command-completion.html) that `aws_completer` is only available for UNIX-like systems

> On Unix-like systems, the AWS CLI includes a command-completion feature

And my version of AWS CLI that I downloaded from AWS doesn't have any `aws_completer` packages or scripts indeed.

Is there a way to enable completion on Windows?

Answer (score 4):

If you're fond of the completion mode, I would highly recommend looking at the [aws shell](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-shell) tool described as:

> An integrated shell for working with the AWS CLI.

It has tab completion by default and provides guidance in the choice of all the available option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PowerShell 5.1 (/PowerShell Core) you can use this PS Module - https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWSCompleter/
Just `Install-Module AWSCompleter` in PowerShell and you'll have tab-completion running.